# Fit SVM on a pandas data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, svm, sklearn-pandas

I have a pandas data frame named `dataset` and I exported the first two columns of it as `X` and the last column which is named "Class" as `y`:

```
X = dataset.drop('Class', axis=1)
y = dataset['Class']
```

Then using the following lines of code, I tried to fit SVM using these data:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20)
```

After that, using the two lines below, I tried to train the SVM but I got the following error.

```
SupportVectorClassModel = SVC()
SupportVectorClassModel.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

[image: The SVM Error]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: print(df.columns) what columns are the features of you input ?

Comment: @ansev The output of the `print` is "Index(['Column_One', 'Column_Two', 'Class'], dtype='object')"

Comment: in what form are Your class data?

Comment: Looks like the problem is with your data, everything passed to SVN (both X, and y) has to be a number. 
Please run below code and update the result in your post:
dataset.dtypes
dataset.isna().sum()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to convert your dataframe into the list. then split and fit into model

after you split the dataframe into X and Y, convert it into list by using `values` function or `tolist` function. i.e

```py
X = dataset.drop('Class', axis=1)
y = dataset['Class']
# assuming X has multiple columns and y only one column
X = X.values
y = y['Class'].tolist()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20)
```

Comment: Could you please be a little more explicit?

Comment: I update my answer

Comment: if you prefer using NumPy array, after `X = X.values`, you can convert X with `X = np.array(X)`